# Dropdown list is not working in Navbar Component

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I've been making a project in Angular with a backend of Node (and Express) and I'm having some dificulties because I have a dropdown list which is common to all my pages and is located in the navbar component. The only problem is that when I press in "Opções" (Settings) the options bellow don't show up. I've tried to rename the references and play with it by trying multiple aproaches but without success. The navbar I'm using was took from a bootstrap template.

Here is the code of the Navbar Component:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar navbar-dark fixed-top" style="background-color: orange;">
  <a style="font-weight: bold;" class="navbar-brand">E-Tour</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 20px;" class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/home']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 20px;" class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/login']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">Pacotes</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 20px; " class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/produtor']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">Empresa</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 20px; " class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/admin']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">Administrador</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 20px;" class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/cliente']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" *ngIf="userSatus$">{{nome}}</a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown ml-3">

        <!-- This is the part where I click and it doesn't open the dropdown -->
        <a style="margin-right: 2.5em; color: ghostwhite; font-size: 20px;" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">  
          Opções
        </a>

        <!-- Those are the options that are never shown -->
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/login']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" *ngIf="!userSatus$">Login</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider" *ngIf="!userSatus$"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/registo']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">Registar Cliente</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/registerProdutor']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">Registar Empresa</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider" *ngIf="userSatus$"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/logout']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" (click)="logout()" *ngIf="userSatus$">Logout</a>
        </div>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I'm trying to reuse a project front-end I used with angular 8. Could it be related? 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do other bootstrap features work?

Comment: No @Joel, now that you mention. I noticed they don't.

Comment: I think maybe you're not including bootstrap then, the dropdown configuration seems correct to me. Make sure you are loading some bootstrap javascript file in your app. Also, have you considered using [Angular Bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home)? It's quite different from regular bootstrap, but more Angular like, if you are just starting on your project then I'd definitely recommend using it.